# Loop through all posts, show attachment if there (WordPress)

Tags: php, wordpress

I've created two simple `foreach` loops: one for all posts, one for all attachments. I want it show every post title, and if there is an attachment, show that attachment.

I have, thus far:

```
$get_posts_array = array( 'posts_per_page' => 3, 'post_type' => 'post' );
$get_posts = get_posts( $get_posts_array );

foreach ($get_posts as $post)
{
    the_title();

    $get_images_array = array( 'posts_per_page' => 1, 'post_type' => 'attachment' );
    $get_images = get_posts($get_images_array);

    if ($get_images)
    {
        foreach ( $get_images as $post )
        {
        ?>
            <li> <?php the_attachment_link( $post->ID ) ;?> </li>
        <?php
        } 
    }
}
?>
```

However, it is not working as expected.

It retrieves every post title, but uses the same first attachment for all posts.

Any help would be great (I'm inexperienced with PHP, so this could be completely buggy).

Answer (score 0):

From the code that you provided, what you are saying is loop through all the posts and for each post loop through all the attachments and return the first attachment, then move to the next post. You need to have an identifier that ties the attachments to the posts. Example: 
you have an array of posts with ids 1,3,5,7. As you loop through the array of posts you want to grab the attachments that are associated with the specific post id that you are currently looping through.

Hope that helps. I am not versed in WordPress syntax but I would assume it would be something along the lines of...

`$get_images_array = array( 'posts_per_page' => 1, 'post_type' => 'attachment', 'post_id' => $post->ID );`